# Building a Window exe using MinGW, Windows-7 in virtual machine

Tags: gcc, build, windows-7, mingw

I'm working in Windows 7, 64 bit, running in a Virtual Box machine on a (recent-ish) Mac with Intel processor.

I have MinGW installed:

```
gcc -dumpmachine
>>> x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

I am trying to compile a Windows exe for [this code](https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/L8_ANGLES_2_7_0.tgz) (Landsat-8 routines for solar and satellite angle calculations):

```
gcc -I ias_lib -o l8_angle.exe -c l8_angle.c
```

which gives me no errors or warnings when run, and creates `l8_angle.exe` as expected. When opened, the `exe` gives:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows
>   you're running. Check your computer's system information to see
>   whether you need an x86 (32-bit) for x64 (64-bit) version of the
>   program, and then contact the software publisher.

Is it possible to compile this program on my setup?

If you're wondering I *can* run `make` on the Mac OS side to get a Linux executable, but I need a Windows executable for my production machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to compile successully by echoing the `gcc` statements in both `makefile`s:

```
@echo $(value INCS)
```

which for some reasom prints the completely assembled `gcc` command. I then confirmed what the selected flags did and saw that they were all equally appropriate for a Windows build.

The build commands were then:

```
cd ias_lib

gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_angle_gen_calculate_angles_rpc.c -o ias_angle_gen_calculate_angles_rpc.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_angle_gen_read_ang.c -o ias_angle_gen_read_ang.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_angle_gen_utilities.c -o ias_angle_gen_utilities.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_angle_gen_initialize.c -o ias_angle_gen_initialize.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_angle_gen_write_image.c -o ias_angle_gen_write_image.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_angle_gen_find_scas.c -o ias_angle_gen_find_scas.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_geo_convert_dms2deg.c -o ias_geo_convert_dms2deg.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_math_compute_unit_vector.c -o ias_math_compute_unit_vector.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_math_compute_vector_length.c -o ias_math_compute_vector_length.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_math_find_line_segment_intersection.c -o ias_math_find_line_segment_intersection.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_logging.c -o ias_logging.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_misc_create_output_image_trim_lut.c -o ias_misc_create_output_image_trim_lut.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_misc_convert_to_uppercase.c -o ias_misc_convert_to_uppercase.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_misc_write_envi_header.c -o ias_misc_write_envi_header.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_odl_free_tree.c -o ias_odl_free_tree.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_odl_get_field.c -o ias_odl_get_field.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_odl_read_tree.c -o ias_odl_read_tree.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_parm_provide_help.c -o ias_parm_provide_help.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_parm_read.c -o ias_parm_read.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_parm_map_odl_type.c -o ias_parm_map_odl_type.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_parm_check_ranges.c -o ias_parm_check_ranges.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c ias_satellite_attributes.c -o ias_satellite_attributes.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c landsat8.c -o landsat8.o
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -c lablib3.c -o lablib3.o

ar -r libl8ang.a ias_angle_gen_calculate_angles_rpc.o ias_angle_gen_read_ang.o ias_angle_gen_utilities.o ias_angle_gen_initialize.o ias_angle_gen_write_image.o ias_angle_gen_find_scas.o ias_geo_convert_dms2deg.o ias_math_compute_unit_vector.o ias_math_compute_vector_length.o ias_math_find_line_segment_intersection.o ias_logging.o ias_misc_create_output_image_trim_lut.o ias_misc_convert_to_uppercase.o ias_misc_write_envi_header.o ias_odl_free_tree.o ias_odl_get_field.o ias_odl_read_tree.o ias_parm_provide_help.o ias_parm_read.o ias_parm_map_odl_type.o ias_parm_check_ranges.o ias_satellite_attributes.o landsat8.o lablib3.o 

cd ..

gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -I./ias_lib/ -I./ -c -o l8_angles.o l8_angles.c
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -march=nocona -mfpmath=sse -msse2  -I./ias_lib/ -I./ -c -o angles_api.o angles_api.c
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -I./ias_lib/ -I./ -o l8_angles.exe ias_lib/libl8ang.a l8_angles.o angles_api.o -L./ias_lib/ -ll8ang -lm
```

where the only change was in the final line, `l8_angles.exe` rather than `l8_angles`. If anyone has a more straightforward way, I would love to see it.